# I got strange results from Xor gate via python

Tags: python, xor

Using Python's function definition, I created a function that returns True if only one of the two inputs is true.

```py
def xor(a, b):
    if a or b:
        if not a and b:
            r = True
        else:
            r = False
    else:
        r = False
    return r
if xor(True, False):
    print('yes')
if xor(True, True):
    print('no')
```

The result of my thinking is

```
yes
```

But Nothing came out as a result.
Strangely, there were no errors,

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 3):

As per `XOR` definition: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

```py
def xor(a,b):
    return (not a and b) or (a and not b)
```

Alternatively:

```py
def xor(a,b):
    return (a or b) and (not a or not b)
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic used is wrong. You need a parenthesis to check when both inputs are false.

```py
def xor(a, b):
    if a or b:
        if not (a and b):
            r = True
        else:
            r = False
    else:
        r = False
    return r
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the built in xor operator `^`?
Example:

```
>>> True ^ False
True
>>> False ^ False
False
>>> True ^ True
False
>>> False ^ True
True
>>>
```